# How to mask license key of premium WordPress themes or plugin

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I bought a WordPress theme or plugin with a license key.
I used that WordPress theme or plugin on a client/customer website.
However, I don't like the client/customer to be abusing the license that I used on their website. Any idea on how to hide/mask the license key so that the client/customer won't see it visibly and use it irresponsibly?

Comment: You want your customer to use this license key + he have access to this hosting account?
In that case you will not be able to hide the key.
Normally this license keys are limited to 1 Domain name, in that case there should not be a problem showing the key.

Answer (score 0):

The license key will most likely still be somewhere in the database or in one of the files. If that is not an issue, then you can probably hide/mask the license key if it is mentioned in the WP dashboard somewhere by either:

- Hiding it by using CSS (but it will still be visible in the DOM structure behind the scenes, for example when the client inspects the HTML)
- Removing it by some custom PHP code if possible, but this will depend on how/where the license key is being shown and is more difficult to do

I hope this helps.

***Note:*** If you do buy a license for a client's site, then you often buy it for that particular site, so I don't think it's a huge issue that your client can see the license key. Unless maybe it's an agency license, but I don't think it would be shown in that case.